# How can I download WSO2 Developer studio?

Tags: download, wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I am trying to download WSO2 Developer studio, ask me to enter my credentials and nothings happens. I am using macOS. How can I download WSO2 Developer studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find releases of Developer Studio [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/releases)

Comment: Thanks, which platform can I run? Ubuntu, macOS or windows?

Comment: No worries. So you'll see (for example https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/releases/tag/v6.3.0) that there are distributions for all three.

Comment: :) thanks MM. Last question, I have WSDL document and I want os use them to create a rest api. For this scenario (rest-to-soap-to-rest) where I can documentation?

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Working+with+Proxy+Services && https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Working+with+JSON+Message+Payloads#WorkingwithJSONMessagePayloads-ConvertingapayloadbetweenXMLandJSON should get you started nicely ;)

Comment: Hey @Nick; for your information: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Generate+REST+API+from+SOAP+Backend